# Could a GPU be Programmed and/or Modified to Carry Out CPU Instructions?

Tags: gpu, cpu

I was wondering if a GPU could behave like a CPU if modified or programmed to do so. If there is a way, I would also like to know how that could be done. The reason why is, well, sometimes I do that kind of stuff as experiments, just for fun. Plus, if it isn't a big hassle, then it would be much better than buying an expensive processor just to get better performance. I usually don't need my GPU, only because I use my computer for the simplest of things. My other computer, that's a slightly different story (because I use it for video playback), but you get the idea.

Comment: GPU's are Turing Complete.  Therefore, it is possible.  Whether it is at all practical is another matter.  I doubt it is, other than as an intellectual exercise; GPU's are optimized to do very different things than CPU's.  See also http://superuser.com/questions/308771/why-are-we-still-using-cpus-instead-of-gpus

Comment: Yeah, you're certainly right that it wouldn't be logical. However, like I said, it would be kinda interesting to see the result as an experiment, at least in my own perspective.

Comment: I look forward to seeing the result of your efforts.

Comment: Indeed. If you can accomplish this and provide a worthwhile speedup over a CPU for the average application, you'll be rich.

Comment: Maybe, I'll be rich. I was also hoping to program an application that could switch GPU modes, like you could set it to behave like a GPU like it usually does, or you could set it to behave like a CPU. I don't have that much programming experience, so who knows. But it could be useful for people who don't entirely need graphics acceleration and just want to use their computer for general purpose activity. I'll give it some thought, and maybe you're right; I could become rich. It just depends on if people think its useful or not. But if anyone else would like to share some thoughts, fell free.

Comment: @RobertHarvey, Thanks, however, I do not think I'll be doing this until I have a bit more knowledge about these kind of things, which might turn out to be a few years, or maybe I won't do it at all, but that's unlikely.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it's called [GPGPU](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General-purpose_computing_on_graphics_processing_units) (general purpose GPU), and with it you could program some CPU-like workloads on your GPU using languages like [CUDA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CUDA) or [OpenCL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenCL).

Of course this method doesn't work well with any workload, the CPU is still much better in single-threaded hard-to-parallelize codes, or codes with complicated control flow (due to branch predictors) or memory locality (due to better caching and prefetching). GPGPUs are mostly better for performing very straight-forward highly parallel vectorizable code.

In fact, this method of computation caught enough traction to create a new lines of products, (such as [Xeon Phi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xeon_Phi), formely Larrabee), and enhancing existing GPUs (e.g. [Tesla/Fermi](http://cseweb.ucsd.edu/classes/fa12/cse141/pdf/09/GPU_Gahagan_FA12.pdf), and others)

**EDIT**
Having reread your question - if you mean running actual CPU ISA on such GPGPU, not just some general CPU task, then the best bet is Xeon Phi mentioned above, it's intended to be based on the same ISA as the CPU (it's the only x86 GPGPU I know of).

Comment: Ah, yes. But I'm afraid the GPU I currently own is not a general purpose GPU. There would be no point in buying one, just so I could program it. But that does answer my question, so thanks!

Comment: @spicedawgx, check if it supports one of the 2 languages above

Comment: GPUs are weak with complicated control flow not so much because of weak branch prediction but the SIMD-orientation. While GPUs allow greater divergence of "threads" (comparable to SIMD data channel) than pure SIMD (even with predication), divergence is more limited than on CPUs and reduces performance. GPUs are also throughput- rather than latency-oriented with respect to caches and memory controllers (though integrated CPU-GPU chips seem to use CPU-oriented memory controllers), so if latency is not hidden by the parallelism things like traversing a linked list are even slower.